# iFrame only works for first array?

Tags: php, fancybox

I'm using FancyBox to contain my iframes, but it only works for the first array. Here's what the array looks like:

```
$gallery_items = array(
array("img_src" => "gallery/thumb_1.jpg", "link" => "gallery/profile1.txt"),
array("img_src" => "gallery/thumb_2.jpg", "link" => "gallery/profile2.txt"),
```

and so on, and then here is how it is produced:

```
echo '<li><a id="various3" href ="' . $current_gallery_item["link"] . '"><img src="' . $current_gallery_item["img_src"] . '" /></a></li>';
```

the `id="various3"` is how FancyBox tells its an iframe. But, it only works for the first array.

Comment: The statement *it only works for the first array* is confusing and misleading. After visiting your site, it is clear that you mean, it only works for the first item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Revised answer:**

It seems you don't want iFrames but just load the content via Ajax. Your problem is that every element has the same ID. If you attach Fancybox via

```
 $('#various3').fancybox();
```

then it will only be applied to the first element, because IDs **have to be unique**.

Use classes instead:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($gallery_items as $item): ?>
     <li>
         <a class="various3" href ="<?php echo $item['link']; ?>">
             <img src="<?php echo $item["img_src"]; ?>" />
         </a>
     </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

And jQuery:

```
$('a.various3').fancybox();
```

---

If you really want to have iFrames, you can just add the `iframe` class to the link elements:

```
<a class="various3 iframe" ...>
```

This will automatically tell Fancybox to use iFrames.

See also [*Fancybox - How to use*](http://fancybox.net/howto).

Comment: Yeah I did this, and it works! I also changed all the txt files to basic html files so I could style them better

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach($gallery_items as $current_gallery_item){
    echo '<li><a id="various3" href ="' . $current_gallery_item["link"] . 
          '"><img src="' . $current_gallery_item["img_src"] . '" /></a></li>';
  }
```

Might work

Answer (score 1):

You used the same id (namely, "various3") for several elements.
This will not work this way.
Every id should be unique.

assign some class to A-tags and use it:

```
$("#various3")
```

--->

```
$(".various3")
```